# JAVA writing and loading an Object ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, ioexception, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a program about students (saving the name, age and other information into objects and storing those objects into an arrayList). So far so good, I even got the JFrames to work exactly how I want them but the problem shows up when I try to write all that information in a text file.

How can I do that?

I tried the FileOutputStream with the ObjectOutputStream but I'm most likely not doing it right since I keep getting an IOException.

An example of a program storing an arrayList with 2 or more Objects containing 2 or more variables each is pretty much what I'm looking for.

As for the loading of that saved array, I think I can figure it out but an explaination on that would still be apreciated.

I've seen a couple of times on different websites people suggesting to do
(but it gives me an IOException)

```
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("FileName.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    oos.writeObject(myObjectArrayList);
```

Comment: What `IOException` are you getting?

Comment: Although it makes no technical difference, it would be better practice to use a different file extension, such as .dat or .ser. It simply helps define the contents of a file.

Comment: @BlackBox s/format/extension/. The _format_ of the file doesn't really change.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks, was a bad choice of words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While serializing your ArrayList to a file you need to make sure the object that list contains are also serializable. So make sure your Student class implements `Serializable` interface.

Comment: It clearly states that I'm supposed to avoid this sort of thing but... Thanks a lot I've been stuck on this all day.

Answer (score 3):

By default `ArrayList` is `Serializable`.

But the Objects inside the list also must implement `Serializable` `interface`.

While writing make sure that your `Student`  class  implemented the [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)